# Numerical Solution of the Advection Dispersion equation

Tags: numerical-analysis, time-integration, advection-diffusion

I am facing a simple (at first glance) problem. I need to implement a numerical scheme for the solution of the first order wave propagation equation with chromatic dispersion included. My original problem is (for a forward propagating wave):

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} = -\frac{ \partial u}{ \partial x} - \frac{i \beta_2}{2} \frac{ \partial^2 u}{ \partial t^2},
\end{equation} 
where $c$ is the velocity of light, $u$ is the (complex) envelope of the field, $\beta_2$ is the 2nd order dispersion coefficient. Assume also that the wave is propagating inside a ring cavity of length , say, L where I take periodic boundary conditions: $u(x+L,t) = u(x,t)$ and also that at $t=0$ we know $u(x,0) $ and $u_t(x,0)$.

I am trying to implement a time-stepping numerical scheme and in the process I tried the following:

1) MOL approach, where I do semidiscretization along $x$, reduce the set of equations to a system of first order ODEs (by setting $v = \dot{u}$) and I establish a system: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{v} \\ \dot{u} \end{bmatrix} = A \begin{bmatrix} v \\ u \end{bmatrix} . 
\end{equation}

When I solve the corresponding ODEs via 4th Runge-Kutta, Crank-Nicholson , or simply precomputing the matrix exponential, unfortunatelly, all my solutions eventually blow up to Inf. I implemented the periodic boundary conditions by modifying the matrix $A$ as $A \leftarrow PA$ , where $P$ is the identity matrix with the first row identical copy of the last row.

I also tried a simple finite differences approach where the spatial derivative is approximated via an upwind FD (first order) but to no avail.

Lastly I tried a strang splitting approach based on the two equations: 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{c}\dot{u} &= -\frac{\delta u }{\delta x} \\
\frac{1}{c}\dot{u} &= -\frac{i\beta_2}{2}\frac{\delta^2 u }{\delta t^2} ,
\end{align}

where this time the solution does not blow up but it looks somehow unphysical.

Does someone here know a stable and possibly higher than first order time-stepping scheme for this equation? Please, note that a solution based on a Fourier transform in $x$ is also not a good option for me because I would like to have the flexibility to implement different non-periodic boundary conditions. I would also dislike substituting the second order derivative in time with one in space due to the fact that this complicates the implementation of boundary conditions.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\partial^2/\partial t^2$ or $\partial^2/\partial x^2$?

Comment: The second derivative is in time.

Comment: Are you familiar with [von Neumann stability analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis)? That would give you some insight under which conditions your discretization is stable

Comment: this question has been also asked on [physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196379/152812) before any answers were posted here.

Answer (score 3):

When you discretize a PDE and your discretization blows up, the correct response is not "let's ignore that result and try a different discretization".  That's like trying to fix your car by randomly replacing parts.  Instead, you should stop and investigate until you understand what is wrong, then correct that.

I see three possibilities here:

1. Your code has a bug.
2. Your problem is not well-posed, so the numerical solution is **correctly** blowing up.
3. The problem is well-posed and your numerical method is correctly implemented, but the method is unstable.

There is not enough information in your question to rule out any of these three possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If $\beta_2$ is piece-wise constant the equation is solvable by Fesnel integrals so that you can develop approximte solution based on the boundary conditions.
You have to introduce a co-moving frame and solve from there.